# Is it possible to view long commits in Github?

Tags: user-interface, github, commit

I made a commit in Github for Windows just now with an exceptionally long message. Even with the window maximized, I can't read the whole thing, and more importantly it doesn't let me scroll down to look at the file changes. Just make a long commit as a test and you should see what I'm talking about. I'm not a fan of typing in a console to do things that should be done with a GUI, so I'd love to know about a way to fix this. Google offers nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a report with Github as well, and got the response:

> Thanks for the report! I just tested this, and hit the same issue as well. I'm going to file a ticket for our Windows developers to take a look at.

So it looks like it's not possible right now, and apparently I'm the only person in the world that writes commit messages longer than 60 lines.

Comment: I don't understand this attraction other programmers always seem to have to command lines. I like to have them so I can use them when I need to, but GUIs are so much easier (when they're designed well, that is).